# How to disable TouchableOpacity using useRef() Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, react-hooks

I have a `TouchableOpacity` button which I want to disable and don't want to cause a re-render in this component so I wondered if I can disable it using `useRef` hook.
 I tried in few ways and didn't manage to do it.

Here's an example -

```
const disableBtn = useRef(false);

  function onPressHandler() {
      disableBtn.current.setAttribute('disabled', true);
 //or disableBtn.current = true
  }
 return ( 
      <View  >

         <TouchableOpacity
          ref={disableBtn}
//or disabled={disableBtn.current}         
          onPress={() => {
            onPressHandler();
          }}
        >
          <Text  >Reset Statistics</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It won't be disabled if there's no rerender.

Comment: If you want the button to become visibly disabled, it must be rerendered. If you want to make it invisibly disabled, then simply `onPressHandler() => {if (disableBtn.current === true) return; //do nothing }` Then set the ref to true wherever you want.

Comment: If you would like to prevent re-rendering your button, it is better to split this component and use `React.memo`.

Comment: @PeterTam It's about not re-rendering the **whole** component, I put here only small part of it for the question.